# How to iterate through an array of coordinates to draw a CGPath?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, cgpath

We have an array of coordinates and we want to loop through them to draw a path.  This is how it looks with the values hardcoded:

```
 func createPath(){
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7915055, y: -96.8028408))//1
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.79174845, y: -96.80252195))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7919914, y: -96.8022031))//2
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.791501100000005, y: -96.80235195))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7910108, y: -96.8025008))//3
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.791301700000005, y: -96.8020985))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7915926, y: -96.8016962))//4
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.79154905, y: -96.8022685))
        
    }
```

but we are trying not to hardcode and instead create a function that takes an array of coordinates like this:

```
 func create(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: coordinate.x, y:coordinate.y))//error
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinate.x, y: coordinate.y))//error
        }
    }
```

The issue is how to get the first coordinate in array for the "path.move" and then use the additional coordinates to use in the "path.addLine" part of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enumerate the array and test its index:

```
  for (index, coordinate) in coordinates.enumerated() {
        if index == 0 {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: coordinate.longitude, y:coordinate. latitude))
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinate.longitude, y: coordinate.latitude))
        }
  }
```

also notice that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not have `x` nor `y` but `longitude` and `latitude`

Answer (score 0):

There's a convenience `CGContext.addLines(between:)` method for doing just that. Here's the description from the docs:

> Calling this convenience method is equivalent to calling the move(to:)
> method with the first value in the points array, then calling the
> addLine(to:) method for each subsequent point until the array is
> exhausted. After calling this method, the path's current point is the
> last point in the array.

Usage:

```
let cgPoints = coordinates.map { CGPoint(x: $0.longitude, y: $0.latitude) } 
ctx.addLines(between: cgPoints)
```